# Firebase rules: Unknown variable '$uid'

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I want user to only access their own content, except for one child node: `common`
In `common` child node I want all signed in users to have access.
I have made the following rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      },
        "common" : {
        ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
        ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid"
      }
    }
  }
```

Firebase gives me the error:

> Error saving rules - Line 8: Unknown variable '$uid'.

The error appears in this line: `".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your question, this is your desired database structure:

```json
{
  "userIdA": { // anything here can be written by only userIdA
    "name": "Tom", // this is just example data
    "location": "London",
    /* ... */
  },
  "userIdB": { // anything here can be written by only userIdB
    "name": "Sarah",
    "location": "New York",
    /* ... */
  },
  /* ... other user data ... */
  "common": { // anything here can be written by signed in users
    "data1": "some value",
    "data2": "some other value",
  }
}
```

The rules for this structure would be:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "common" : {
      ".read": "auth != null", // logged in users can read
      ".write": "auth != null" // logged in users can write
    },
    "$uid": { // $uid will be the value of any key, that isn't listed above it (in this case, anything other than "common")
      ".read": "$uid === auth.uid", // only the matching user can read
      ".write": "$uid === auth.uid" // only the matching user can write
    }
  }
}
```

**Note:** This data structure isn't very secure. Allow read/write access to only what you need in your database. With this structure, any user could come along and open up their console and delete everything under `"/common"`. You may consider adding `".validate"` rules to make sure certain keys (such as `"/common/data1"`) are only strings.

Answer (score 1):

The `$uid` must be inside `users` Document like the example below :

```
 {
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```